# Pandas dataframe assignment by pair of (row,column) values

Tags: python, pandas, variable-assignment, lookup

I know that using pandas lookup I can choose particular dataframe cells using pairs of (row,column) values. For example

```
frame = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
frame.lookup([0,1],[1,2])
```

gives me

```
array([2, 6], dtype=int64)
```

Is there a similar way to assign values to cells? I am looking for something like this:

Pseudocode:

```
frame.lookup([0,1],[1,2]) = [7,8]
```

Comment: No, Pandas doesn't support advanced indexing like that out-of-box. Even `lookup` is [deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39171) in version 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any Pandas solution for that.
But if I'll have to do it on my own - below code should work.

```py
frame = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
#    0  1  2
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  4  5  6

frame.lookup([0,1],[1,2])
# array([2, 6])

def set_dataframe_values(dataframe, coords, values):
    dataframe_ = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)
    for x__y, value in zip(coords, values):
        x, y = x__y
        dataframe_[y][x] = value
    return dataframe_
   
set_dataframe_values(frame, coords=[(0,1), (1,2)], values=[7,8])
#    0  1  2
# 0  1  7  3
# 1  4  5  8

frame.lookup([0,1],[1,2])
# array([7, 8])
```